# What is the benefit of Model / ModelMap over ModelAndView in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What is the benefit of Model / ModelMap over ModelAndView in Spring MVC? When we should use Model/ModelMap instead of ModelAndView.

I checked many sites but answers are not clear!

Answer (score 0):

I have read few pages and answers and there doesn't seem to be any differences really. Matter of taste. `ModelAndView` object wraps model and view. It seems that that is also done implicitly when returning a `String`. Use the way you prefer.

You can read here about the return types: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types

Comment: No, there is one difference I read somewhere. ModelMap is used when there is a need for sending Model data from one controller method to another controller method. We can pass the model data as an argument to another controller method. But just wanted to get more explanation by example.

Comment: @SuryaN, why cannot we can do the same for modelandview?

Answer (score -1):

1. Model

   Let’s start with the most basic concept here – the Model. Simply put, the model can supply attributes used for rendering views.

   To provide a view with usable data, we simply add this data to its Model object. Additionally, maps with attributes can be merged with Model instances:

   ```
   @GetMapping("/showViewPage")
   public String passParametersWithModel(Model model) {
       Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put("spring", "mvc");
       model.addAttribute("message", "Baeldung");
       model.mergeAttributes(map);
       return "viewPage";
   }
   ```
2. ModelMap

   Just like the Model interface above, ModelMap is also used to pass values to render a view. The advantage of ModelMap is it gives us the ability to pass a collection of values and treat these values as if they were on a Map:

   ```
   @GetMapping("/printViewPage")
   public String passParametersWithModelMap(ModelMap map) {
       map.addAttribute("welcomeMessage", "welcome");
       map.addAttribute("message", "Baeldung");
       return "viewPage";
   }
   ```
3. ModelAndView

   The final interface to pass values to a view is the ModelAndView.
   This interface allows us to pass all the information required by Spring MVC in one return:

   ```
   @GetMapping("/goToViewPage")
   public ModelAndView passParametersWithModelAndView() {
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("viewPage");
       modelAndView.addObject("message", "Baeldung");
       return modelAndView;
   }
   ```

Comment: simply copy and paste from url:https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view